# Where can I see all available Playstation 3 avatars?

Tags: psn

I'd like to find a better PlayStation Network avatar than the ones that come stock and standard with the PlayStation 3.  Where can I go online to find and view all that are available?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several available on the PlayStation Store. Most of them are not free ($ 0.49), but it is possible to find free. You have only to run on the PlayStation Store, select Themes and avatars, and then selects Avatars. The ranking is depending on the game.

Comment: take a look to this new from playstation Blog: http://blog.us.playstation.com/2011/01/24/more-avatar-options-coming-to-playstation-network/

Comment: That's the blog post that inspired my question.  Serendipitous!

Comment: You can now also view them in your web browser at the [Sony Entertainment Network Online Store](https://store.sonyentertainmentnetwork.com/#!/en-us/all-ps3-avatars/cid=STORE-MSF77008-PS3ALLAVATARS).

Comment: Yeah, that's right! This is one more way to see available avatars! Not sure it was possible 2 years ago!?

Answer (score 3):

If you are a PSN Plus subscriber, there are a ton of free ones available.  Otherwise you can get them from the PSN Store.  I believe there are some free ones in there as well but, most cost a little bit.